# How to keep the values in the input fields when submitting a form in PHP?

Tags: php, html, jquery, forms, form-submit

I have a form with a table with dynamic fields and dynamic rows. So initially the table contains one row with two fields, when I fill them both and click Enter, a jquery function will create a new row below.

When time comes to Submit the form, I am checking if there is any empty field, and if there is any it displays an error BUT the problem is here, it clears all fields. How can I still keep them when submitting?

He**re is the HTML:**

```
 <form action="" method="post">
           <button type="submit" class="btn" name="add_device">Add devices</button>
        <?php foreach ($dev_type_results as $row) {
        } ?>
        <table id="ble_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>Serial no.</th>
                <th>IMEI</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="serial_no[]" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['serial_no'])) { echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['serial_no']);} ?>" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="inputs lst" name="imei[]" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['imei'])) { echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['imei']); } ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

**jquery function :**

```
        var i = $('table tr').length;

    $(document).on('keyup', '.lst', function(e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13) {
            html = '<tr>';
            html += '<td>' + i + '</td>';

            <?php foreach ($dev_type_results as $row) {
            }
                html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="serial_no[]' + i + '"  value="<?php if (isset($_POST['serial_no'])) { echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['serial_no']);} ?>"/></td>';
                html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs lst" name="imei[]' + i + '" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['imei'])) { echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['imei']);} ?>"/></td>';

            html += '</tr>';
            $('table').append(html);
            $(this).focus().select();
            i++;
        }
    });

    $(document).on('keydown', '.inputs', function(e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13) {
            var index = $('.inputs').index(this) + 1;
            $('.inputs').eq(index).focus();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

**Below for brevity I will just post the PHP code where I validate:**

```
if (count(array_filter($_POST['serial_no'])) < count($_POST['imei'])) {
  array_push($errors, "Found empty field in Serial no. column");
}else{
 //call function to post to database
}
```

**I have tried already by using global variables but it doesn't work. What else can I try?**

Comment: first if you are processing the form in the same page, the form must have this action:

```<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >```

it will send the form to "self", the url of the page you are into. I don't know if it works with an empty action.

Comment: an useful shortcut: ```<?php echo $variable; ?>``` can be replaced with ```<?=$variable;?>``` it does the same thing! :-)

Comment: What is the value of `$dev_type_results`? It is never assigned anywhere in this code.

Comment: @Sherif its an array that contains the fields I am fetching from database. I dont think its necessary for this question that's why I didn't post it.

Comment: @Funder thanks for ur suggestions but it didn't fix the problem

Comment: It's very necessary. It defines the outcome of your code.

Comment: @Sherif why so? The data I am fetching are fine and have nothing to do with the way I am submitting the form.

Comment: @Funder I just updated my HTML code, check it out.

Comment: I suppose that you want to create N rows, depending on how many records are returned from the database. But it's hard to suggest what to fix without seeing the parts involved in the problem. If the code is too long, or hard to prepare for this post, you can paste in https://jsfiddle.net/ session, and share the link here, so we can see the whole thing. Don't worry if the php code doesn't run there, it's just to read the code. thanks

Comment: @Funder the question is not about creating rows if you understood it like that. Yes I am creating N rows when user hits Enter. Eitherway, I just posted my code here, please take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/hzcr84Ln/

Comment: Yes I know, but I see a bit of confusion, and in fact the part where you generate the html from php is missing in the snippet above (please edit your question so other users can see if this post can help them or not).

```if ($row['serial_or_imei'] === null || 'both')``` this will not work "both" will always run as it will evaluate to ```true```. You meant ```if ($row['serial_or_imei'] === null || $row['serial_or_imei'] === 'both') ```?. 
Also, what is expected to retur from the array_filter php function? can yo write the concept behind that piece of code? And ```<br/> not </br>```!

Comment: @Funder thanks, I fixed the 'both' mistake. Hmmm generate the HTML from PHP? I am not doing that actually! What do you mean? Btw could you find a solution for saving the values?

Comment: @Funder array_filter function I am checking if any of the arrays is longer than the other one so throw an error.

Comment: have you noticed that the php foreach loop is empty? ```$row``` is null, with the actual code!
I suggest you to do some experiments, and print the contents of the php variables, while you run the code. It seems to me that you are trying to use stuff that for the moment is too complex, before going too far, try to make the code work in the simplest way possible, then when you have more control, it's time to improve it. 
Just use ```empty($_POST['serial_no'])``` to check if a parameter is empty. [Read the documentation of empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty)

Comment: @Funder I am using the `foreach ($dev_type_results as $row) {
            } ?>` just to check whether I should have one or two headers, so, if I place the headers html code inside the for loop it will create a new header for each item of the array and I dont want that.

Comment: Just use ```count($dev_type_results)``` if you want to know how many results have been found. Another error, inside of the js-php part have you noticed that you are creating fields with a wrong name? ```name="serial_no' + i + '"``` must be ```name="serial[]"```. It's a mess mate, and this is wrong too ```name="serial_no[]' + i + '"```. And please, please, check if your query has been executed. If ```$dev_type_results``` is false, then check your error log. I don't want to know what happens in the functions.php file! :-D

Comment: @Funder trust me , its not a mess! I know `serial[]` I have fixed that already but please focus on the question! I tested with single values and works but when I try with arrays I cant save the values. Dont worry about the query, I haven't come there yet, can you see the return and commented out, I am preventing it to reach there. I need to make this work first.

Comment: @Funder would you suggest using Session to keep the values of those arrays? What if arrays are too big, will that cause a problem for the server?

Answer (score 0):

You could add **ids** to the inputs and use javascript to find it and change it's content.

```js
    var Input_1 = document.getElementById(Input_1 - id);
    var Input_2 = document.getElementById(Input_2 - id);
    var Val_1;
    var Val_2;
    var completed = false;
    var i = $('table tr').length;

    $(document).on('keyup', '.lst', function(e) {
      var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
      if (code == 13) {
        html = '<tr>';
        html += '<td>' + i + '</td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="serial_no[]' + i + '"  value="<?php if (isset($_POST['
        serial_no '])) { echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['
        serial_no ']);} ?>
        "/></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs lst" name="imei[]' + i + '" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['
        imei '])) { echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['
        imei ']);} ?>"/></td>';

        html += '</tr>';
        $('table').append(html);
        $(this).focus().select();
        i++;
      }
    });

    $(document).on('keydown', '.inputs', function(e) {
      var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
      if (code == 13) {
        completed = true
        var index = $('.inputs').index(this) + 1;
        $('.inputs').eq(index).focus();
        event.preventDefault();
        Input_1.value = Val_1;
        Input_2.value = Val_2;
      }
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <button type="submit" class="btn" name="add_device">Add devices</button>
      <?php foreach ($dev_type_results as $row) {
            } ?>
      <table id="ble_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <th>No.</th>
          <th>Serial no.</th>
          <th>IMEI</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="serial_no[]" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['serial_no'])) { echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['serial_no']);} ?>" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="inputs lst" name="imei[]" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['imei'])) { echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['imei']); } ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    <?php
        if (count(array_filter($_POST['serial_no'])) < count($_POST['imei'])){
      array_push($errors, "Found empty field in Serial no. column");
    }else{
     //call function to post to database
    }
    ?>
```